# How can I refactor these methods and remove the dependency checks on the first lines

Tags: ruby, refactoring, dependencies

I'm essentially making a form that pre-calculates most of its fields.
So, I have a bunch of methods that rely on previous methods, or should return nil. At the moment I'm doing a series of checks, and I'd like to remove them.

(Ignore the calculations, they are just examples)

```
def age
  return unless dob  # Not so bad... 
  Date.today - dob
end

def age_at_start
  return unless dob && start_date  # Getting worse
  start_date - dob
end

def compensation
  return unless age_at_start && time_worked && salary && staff_rating  # Shoot me now
  some_calculation(age_at_start, time_worked, salary, staff_rating)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It partially depends on what you're *really* doing, aside from the example--without context it's difficult to know what would be the most meaningful under the circumstances.

Can't do much better than:

```
def age
  Date.today - dob if dob
end
```

Same with this one--I wouldn't break out the guard clause yet:

```
def age_at_start
  dob && start_date ? start_date - dob : nil
end
```

Here I'd break out the guard clause, because (a) you can, and (b) IMO testing is easier:

```
def compensation
  some_calculation if can_be_compensated?
end

def can_be_compensated?
  age_at_start && time_worked && salary && staff_rating
end
```

If `some_calculation` is actually 'external' and needs the args, I might wrap it in a method that has access like your original and `can_be_compensated?`.

Comment: I like these. For your second statement, would `dob && start_date && start_date - dob` also work?

Comment: @Anil Not sure, I'd have to try it--it'd look nicer if it, though! Not sure how readable it is; I'd have to think about that. Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
def age
  (Date.today - dob) if dob
end

def age_at_start
  (start_date - dob) if dob && start_date
end

def compensation
  some_calculation(time_worked, age_at_finish, salary, staff_rating) if age_at_start && time_worked && salary && staff_rating
end
```

Comment: Tough to make them shorter than 1 line and readable on the left side. Or drop all checks and make sure your logic never gets here without valid data.

Comment: @Alex First one is, except it's backwards, isn't it?

Comment: I thought you didn't care for content. My bad. Fixed now.

Comment: @Anil Why would you think that? I'm big on correctness, as much as possible. Also, when replying, make sure (a) you're replying to the right person ;) and (b) you use the `@` character, otherwise they may not know you've replied to them.

Comment: @DaveNewton Noted, and noted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I always have trouble when conditionals start getting too long as well. Once thing that helps though is to wrap some of them into individual `methods`. This route will at least provide you with a couple public methods that you can stub out in your tests.

```
def age
  return unless dob
  Date.today - dob
end

def age_at_start
  return unless valid_age_at_start(start_date, dob)
  start_date - dob
end

def compensation
  return unless valid_compensation(age_at_start, time_worked, salary, staff_rating)
  some_calculation(time_worked, age_at_finish, salary, staff_rating)
end

def valid_age_at_start(start_date, dob)
  start_date && dob
end

def valid_compensation(age_at_start, time_worked, salary, staff_rating)
  age_at_start && time_worked && salary && staff_rating
end
```

Or you could create a method that just validates your arguments:

```
def age
  return unless dob
  Date.today - dob
end

def age_at_start
  return unless valid_arguments?(start_date, dob)
  start_date - dob
end

def compensation
  return unless valid_arguments?(age_at_start, time_worked, salary, staff_rating)
  some_calculation(time_worked, age_at_finish, salary, staff_rating)
end

private

def valid_arguments?(*args)
  args.each do |arg|
    return false unless arg
  end
  return true
end
```

Admittedly both routes are still sort of ugly though.

Comment: I thought about a method like that at the start, doesn't reduce complexity very much though.

Comment: Yea, I'm not sure if you'll be able to extract the complexity, but sometimes it helps to not call the complexity directly. So when I encounter stuff like this, unfortunately, I'll sometimes just abstract it into a descriptive method instead. Then just write a test for both. Still, you're right, it's not too much better.

Comment: I don't have an intrinsic problem with things like `valid_arguments?` (although it's actually just `args.all? { |a| a }` or even shorter) but as soon as what "valid" means changes, all hell breaks loose!

Comment: Agreed. I don't particularly like the second solution. `valid_arguments?`, it's only moderately descriptive, but I'm not sure how to succinctly describe a chain of conditions that long.

Comment: I'm not really sure you can, unless there are intermediate refactorings that make sense, or a descriptive DSL--overkill and more-verbose in this case, clearly :)